# Is it recommended to use trigger to create constraint in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have a case that confused and annoyed me for a long time and currently I am struggling whether I should use trigger.
Here I have two table in MYSQL

```
Create table type(
id int primary key not null auto_increment,
class int not null default 0,
name string not null
)

Create table buddy (
id int primary key not null auto_increment,
value string not null)

Create table value (
id int primary key not null auto_increment,
type_id int not null,
buddy_id int default null,
value string not null,
relied_id int default null
foreign key type_id references type(id)
)
```

in this case, there are several rules,

Inside value table, some value may refer to the buddy table, while some are not.

```
if (the buddy_id inside value is not null){ 
   row with this buddy_id should be unique
} else{ 
   could have several instances with the nil buddy_id
}
```

If the buddy_id is nil, which means it does not refer to anything, it could be duplicate.

In my module, I will receive the message from my colleague's queue and then do the following things:

```
1), if I detect inside the message, there is a buddy_id, I need to use sql to check whether the value with this buddy_id is already in the database, if yes, just ignore, else should create one.
2), else, directly create a new one
```

in the first case, my colleague is keep sending me the duplicate message, as after I get "whether the instance with this buddy_id is already inside database" as result as false, it still needs to take sometime to do some logic and create a new instance, then insert into database. There maybe a gap between I got the result and insert.

During this period, another message may come with the same buddy_id and it will trigger another go routine or thread, but the first insert is still not done, in this case, it will also find "instance with this buddy_id is not inside databases, I should create one".

As a result, more than one instance with same buddy_id will be insert into database.
[image]
I think this pic could better illustrate what I am talking, two messages with same buddy_id come one by one, but when message 1 with buddy_id = 10 is processing, before inserting, message 2 comes and find there is no buddy_id = 10, so message 2 also creates an instance in database.

Previously, I tried to lock the table, but the project manager asked me to remove the lock as this value table is a main table and he does not want me to lock the database.

I also had a look of the unique constraint but the case for buddy_id is "if it is nil, no unique, if it is not nil, unique". I think this cannot be done just using the unique key constraint.

So anyone has idea whether I should use trigger to do the check before insert to make sure the instance is not duplicate? Or any other recommended methods?

Thanks.